# Recursively replace regex find with path in the regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, stringbuilder

**My Question** is a design question. Should I use a `StringBuilder` and read the file line-by-line, or should I `replace`?

I'm developing a way to read text from a file. Within the file there can be `@@GOTO:"C:\path\to\more.txt"@@`. I want to replace everything between the two `@@`s with the contents of `C:\path\to\more.txt`. Also, within `more.txt` there could be another `@@GOTO:"C:\path\to\evenmore.txt"@@`. So I'm thinking doing this recursively would be the best.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
private String replaceGoTo(Pattern pattern, String xmlString) throws IOException {
  Matcher match = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
  while (match.find()) {
    String replacText = IOHelper.fileToString(match.group(2));
    String insert = replaceGoTo(pattern, replacText);
    xmlString = xmlString.replace(match.group(1), insert);
  }
  return xmlString;
}
```

But I wonder if that's the most effective way to do it because I'm not using a `StringBuilder` and I could potentially have a lot of information in those Strings.

**Note** It's not broken, I'm just asking about whether there's a better way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honest answer: Use an existing template library like Freemarker or Velocity.

Literal answer: [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) has two methods that come in handy for this kind of situation, [`appendReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and `appendTail()`. Both require you to use StringBuffer, which is unfortunate, but it's the most elegant way to solve such a problem.

Comment: +1 for reference to existing template libraries. If this were a bigger project that's probably the way I'd go!

Comment: @kentcdodds you should look at appendReplacement / appendTail. It is *much* more efficient than what you are doing now.

Comment: Has anyone tried to use a template library for this kind of task? I would like to know whether the template libraries use a stream based approach. Or do they read the entire content of the files into the memory?

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way would be to write a FilterReader that replaces the starting and ending strings while you are reading the file. I don't see the need for a regular expression to replace static data. The following code could do the trick:

```
public class ReplaceFilterReader extends Reader {
    private String match;
    private String replace;

    private BufferedReader in;
    private boolean matched;
    private int currentPos;
    private boolean end = false;

    public ReplaceFilterReader(Reader in, String match, String replace) {
        this.in = new BufferedReader(in);
        this.matched = false;
        this.currentPos = 0;
        this.match = match;
        this.replace = replace;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(CharBuffer target) throws IOException {
        int len = target.remaining();
        char[] cbuf = new char[len];
        int n = read(cbuf, 0, len);
        if (n > 0) {
            target.put(cbuf, 0, n);
        }
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf) throws IOException {
        return this.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        char cb[] = new char[1];
        if (this.read(cb, 0, 1) == -1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return cb[0];
        }
    }

    private int readNext() throws IOException {
        int result = 0;
        if (!matched) {
            this.in.mark(match.length());
            char cb[] = new char[match.length()];
            int n = this.in.read(cb);
            if (n>0) {
                String s = new String(cb);
                if (s.equals(match)) {
                    this.matched = true;
                    if (replace.length()>0) {
                        result = replace.charAt(currentPos);
                        currentPos+=1;
                        if (currentPos == replace.length()) {
                            this.matched = false;
                            this.currentPos = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.matched = false;
                        this.currentPos = 0;
                        result = 0;
                    }

                } else {
                    this.in.reset();
                    result = this.in.read();
                }
            } else {
                result = n;
            }
        } else {
            result = replace.charAt(currentPos);
            currentPos+=1;
            if (currentPos == replace.length()) {
                this.matched = false;
                this.currentPos = 0;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (end) {
            return -1;
        }

        int n = 0;
        int read = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<len && n!=-1; i++) {
            n = this.readNext();
            if (n!=-1 && n!=0) {
                read += 1;
                cbuf[off+i] = (char) n;
            } else if (n==0) {
                i = i-1;
            }
        }

        if (n == -1) {
            end = true;
        }

        return read;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.in.close();
    }
}
```

And you would proceed like this:

```
Reader yourReader = // open file ...
Reader replaceStart = new ReplaceFilterReader(yourReader,"@@GOTO:\"","");
Reader replaceEnd = new ReplaceFilterReader(replaceStart,"\"@@","");
```